# Is there PeriodicWorkRequest equivalent for iOS to use in background?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, background-process, androidx

We are working on Xamarin.Forms app.
One of the mechanisms we need to do is to upload a bunch of images in the background, and in case of failure retry until it works.

For Android, it is quite straightforward:

```
using AndroidX.Work;
...
        PeriodicWorkRequest uploadWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder.From<UploadWorker>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)).Build();
        WorkManager.Instance.Enqueue(uploadWorkRequest);
```

where

```
public class UploadWorker : Worker
{
    public UploadWorker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParameters) : base(context, workerParameters) { }

    public override Result DoWork()
    {
 //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Now obviously this mechanism is not present for iOS, but the functionality to run a task in the background and repeat if it fails should be there.

**Is there PeriodicWorkRequest equivalent for iOS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS we could use **NSTimer** to implement some repeating tasks .

```
_timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), () =>
{
    this.InvokeOnMainThread(()=>{
        //Your code goes here
    });
}
```

**Start the timer**

```
timer.Fire();
```

**Stop the timer** (invoke it when leaving the current ViewController)

```
_timer.Invalidate();
```

Comment: Hi Lucas. I am assuming this will work for the background too. I can see the `this.InvokeOnMainThread`

Comment: For background task you could check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks .

Comment: I can't Lucas, I was asking for a background mechanism. I apologize if I wasn't clear on it.

Comment: Did you check the above link ?

Comment: I had read the article on background work before posting the question, also it is considered good practice for links to be inside the answer and not the comments. Also, links in the answers are also discouraged since they have a tendency to die over time. What is preferred - is a fully contained code solution that can be reused by all the other souls that will need this in the future. Such solutions get +35 in my book, accepted and +1 ;)